# Android : how to create a Object using Reflection and pass constructor parameter?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I'm trying a button using reflection in android, by the following code

```
 public String createView(String classFullName){
        try{
            Class clazz = Class.forName(classFullName);

            Object obj = clazz.newInstance(); // but I need to pass the Context using this;


        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
            return null;
        }
    }
```

but the main problem, is how to pass Context ( which is this in my case ) to the Object since they all should be a View.

Comment: You'll need to get a reference to the constructor that takes the context and then call `newInstance()` on that constructor object.  Take a look here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/constructors.html

Comment: @Blackbelt There is no such method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `Class#newInstance()` is just a convenience method to invoke a zero-arg constructor. If you want to invoke a constructor with arguments, you need to obtain the right `Constructor` instance through reflection using [`Class#getConstructor(Class...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class%3C?%3E...%29), and then call it using [`Constructor#newInstance(Object...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...)).

So:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(classFullName);
Constructor<?> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(Context.class);
Object obj = constructor.newInstance(this);
```